# What is the correct way to init and customize the 2d js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

*Please open your browser console to see the log of the table.

```js
const n = 5;
const m = 4;
const vl = new Array(n).fill(Array.from({length: m}, (v, i) => false))
console.table(vl)
vl[0][0] = true
console.table(vl)
```

I was trying to change only one value of [0][0], but it is changing the whole column as `true`.

Not sure what's happening behind the scene. Maybe is it related to 2d array initialization?

[image]

Comment: this is happening as the reference is same. try with this: `Array.from({length:n}, ()=>Array.from({length: m}, (v, i) => false))`

Answer (score 1):

just use `Array.from` two times and you are good to go

```js
const n = 5;
const m = 4;
const vl = Array.from({length: n}, () =>Array.from({length: m}, (v, i) => false))
console.table(vl)
vl[0][0] = true
console.log(vl)
```